# How to modify preference of a FooterView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

Very basic question:
I'm trying to enable/disable the `FooterView` of a `ListView` dynamically.
Basically I would like to make it clickable through the `setEnable(true/false)` function as soon as the `LocationListener` acquires a new location. I was thinking about a public method that get called from within the `LocationListener.onLocationChange()` method, with no return but it has to change the `FooterView` preference, but I can't figure out how to code it, and if it could work. Any suggestions?

In onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView footerView = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
    myListView.addFooterView(footerView);
    //if (!enabler) footerView.setEnabled(false);
    //else footerView.setEnabled(true);
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {}
    });
}
```

The LocationListener methods

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
    if (null == mLastLocationReading || mLastLocationReading.getTime() > currentLocation.getTime()){
        mLastLocationReading = currentLocation;
        enabler=true;
    }
    if (currentLocation.getTime() > mLastLocationReading.getTime())
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

So even if the Listener find a new location it doesn't trigger the if condition enabling the footerView (where I commented out the code).
I tried to access footerView.setEnable from a method with no joy. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your solution is not working is because `onCreate()` is called only once, when the `Activity` is being created.

Try the following:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private TextView footerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        footerView = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
        myListView.addFooterView(footerView);
        footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
        if (null == mLastLocationReading || mLastLocationReading.getTime() > currentLocation.getTime()){
            mLastLocationReading = currentLocation;
            enableFooterView(true);
        }
        if (currentLocation.getTime() > mLastLocationReading.getTime())
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    private void enableFooterView(boolean enable) {
        footerView.setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, the IDE is giving me an error "cannot resolve symbol" on footerView. Is it because of the scope of the variable?

Comment: Would you mind to briefly explain me how to do it, please? I'm still learning.

Comment: see the `private TextView footerView;` this is called making a variable property.